# Take parameters from Python script and use D3.js to show it on a webpage

Tags: javascript, python, d3.js

The python script I currently deal with has many variables and these keep changing over time. The time period of the change is almost every second. I want to show this on a gauge or using some visualization technique on a webpage. As of now, there is no data transfer from the webpage to the python script.

I don't want to run the script using javascript, just take variable values from it when it is already running.

How do I accomplish this ?